# Единый обработчик для кнопок на нескольких активити

Tags: java, android

Допустим есть два activity
1. Содержит текстовые поля и кнопку перехода на второй activity
2. Содержит три кнопки и текстовое поле

Есть возможность обработать методом 
 `public void onClick(View v)`
кнопки с разных activity?

Comment: Есть, но как правило, не стоит этого делать. Объясните лучше суть проблемы.

Comment: Писать обработчик надо для каждой кнопки или можно кнопки с разных экранов обработать в onclick, интерфейса onlcicklistener? Второй способ не правильный?

Comment: А что общего между кнопками, кроме того что они кнопки и на них можно кликать? Если кнопки делаю разные вещи при нажатии на них, то писать один универсальный обработчик неверно, смахивает на антипаттерн God Object.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что при нажатии на любую из кнопок на одном из возможных activity запускается метод onclick, который по id элемента определяет, какая кнопка была нажата и выполняет предписанные ей действия. Или это масло масленное?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно сделать реализацию передачи содержимого текстового поля из activity в activity, то попробуйте следующее:
Передача из activity в activity

```
 public void ListenerButton() {

        YourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalculate);
        YourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();

                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),YourActivity);
                 myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
                 startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Приём в другом activity:

```
TextView mTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.YourActivity);

       mTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

       mTextview.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
}
```